# PL/SQL - call to stored procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, call, plsqldeveloper

I want to call this proc but want to pass 1 as well as 2 to maj_in.

Is there away to do so ?

XX.wind.delete_major_ven(id_in => app_id_in,maj_in => 1, work_in => 'jira-1', change_in => 'unwind');

Comment: you mean to say that if 1 fails then 2 is used?, in my opinion you can break maj_in to two parameter name maj_in1 and maj_in2 and can use this new parameters as range.

Comment: Otherwise you have to create an object type which will holding your both values but that would be a lengthy process